# How to Access Asp.net Hosted Application Over Interanet?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, host, lan

i am trying to access application over intranet as my system is in network and another system is also on network from which application is running as i can see both system in work group

i tried access system using link

```
http://192.168.1.1/scoring.com
```

`scoring.com is host header` and running on that system successfully it is running on `port 80`

```
i am getting error Http:// error 404 when i run this link
```

one more thing i wanna mention that i have not created domain is it necessary for accessing this hosted application over network ??

Hopes for your suggestion thanks in Advance!